# C++ Calendar (Cannot Get Value of Variable to Return to Main Function)

Tags: c++, project, gregorian-calendar

Okay, so I have this project due for class by the 17th and I was wondering if I could get a bit of help. Basically, we are suppose to create a calendar that prints based on the day the Gregorian Calendar was created. I already figured out how to do the assignment but I am having trouble with leap year.

What I am having a problem with is returning the value of offset back to the main function so it can be used in another function. Perhaps this is a bit too advanced for my skills but I feel like this should be something fairly easy to do.

To give you an idea how leap year works. After the Century Offset does it's calculation, if the year is a leap year, it's suppose to subtract 1. Or in this case decrement. For some reason, the offset will not decrement for a leap year like 2016. If really confused as to why my if statement is not working. Can someone help?

```
//Write a program that will print a calendar for whatever year the user wants.

//Declaring libraries...some I might not need....
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

//Function prototypes
void ComputeCalendar(string [], string [], int, int);
void CenturyOffset(int year, int offset);
const int DAYS_OF_THE_WEEK = 7;
const int MONTHS_OF_THE_YEAR = 12;

//function calls

//Note: Use switch to calculate what day the calendar begins on

//Determines what day that calendar begins on
void CenturyOffset(int year, int offset){
    int c, y, z, s, d;

    c = year / 100;
    y = year % 100;
    z = y / 4;
    s = c + y + z;
    d = s % 7;
    offset = d;
    if (year % 4 == 0 && year % 400 == 0)
        offset--;
    cout << offset << endl;
    }

//function for creating the calendar
void ComputeCalendar(string months[], string days[], int year, int offset) {

    cout << "\n" << setw(50) << year << "\n" << endl;
    int cal;
    int week;
        for(cal=0; cal<MONTHS_OF_THE_YEAR; cal++)
            {
                cout << "\n" << endl;
                cout << setw(3) << months[cal] << " " << year << endl;
                cout << "\n" << endl;
                    for(week=0; week<DAYS_OF_THE_WEEK; week++)
                        {
                            cout << setw(5) << days[week];
                        }
                cout << endl;
            }
        }
//Main function that allows the user to input the year they wish to see
int main(int argc, char*argv[])
{
    int year;
    int offset;
    cout << "What year would you like to see the calendar for? \n" << endl;
    cin >> year;
    cout << "\n" << endl;

        while(year < 1754) //Check if the year was before or after 1754
            {
            cout << "You may not enter a year that is before 1754. \n" << endl;
            cout << "Please enter another year." << endl;
            cin >> year;
            cout << "\n" << endl;
            }
        string days[DAYS_OF_THE_WEEK] = {"SU","MO","TU","WE","TH","FR","SA"};             
//Stores days of the week in an array
        string months[MONTHS_OF_THE_YEAR] = {"January", "February", "March",
                                  "April", "May", "June",
                                  "July", "August", "September",
                                  "October", "November", "December"}; 
//Stores Months of the year in an array
        ComputeCalendar(months, days, year, offset);
        CenturyOffset(year, offset);
}
```

Comment: 1. Please indent the code to make it readable. 2. `using namespace std` is bad - google this

Comment: When I need help calculating leap years, I ask the Oracle for [leap year calculation c++](https://www.google.com/search?q=leap+year+calculation+c%2B%2B&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8) and lots of information comes back.

Comment: Please edit your post with the results of your debugging session.  Be sure to include the input data, expected output, actual output, and indicate which line/statement the code failed at.

Comment: No, I understand how to calculate leap years, it's just not working when the year actually IS a leapyear. There's an IF statement in Century Offset. Whenever I create a separate function for it, it doesn't work.

Comment: Remember, unless you pass by reference or pointer, the compiler will generate a *copy* and pass the *copy* to your function.  The original variable will not be modified.

Comment: So I should try using pointers for that function? Also, I edited the post so hopefully it's a bit better to read.

Comment: Prefer *references* rather than pointers.  Don't use pointers unless no other solution is available.  After you learn the faults of pointers, you can use pointers.

Comment: You may want to remove the C# tag, as this looks more like C++.  They are different languages.  C++ does not have managed data structures nor the CString class.

Answer (score 3):

If you'd like to retain the value of `offset` when `CenturyOffset(...)` exits, change the function signature from:

```
void CenturyOffset(int year, int offset);
```

to

```
void CenturyOffset(int year, int& offset);
```

This way, `offset` is a [reference](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_references.htm).

Other links:

- [Reference (C++)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reference_(C%2B%2B))
- http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reference

---

You may also return the value instead of having it passed as a parameter:

```
int CenturyOffset(int year) {
   int offset;
   // ...
   return offset
}
```

in main:

```
int offset = CenturyOffset(year);
// ...
```

Comment: Another alternative is to return the `offset`.

Comment: Indeed. I can include that.

Comment: Yeah, I did that and it still didn't work. The IF Statement I created for leapyear which is this  [code] if (year % 4 == 0 && year % 400 == 0)
        offset--; [/code] isn't working. It doesn't execute

Comment: @JamalWilliams you'll need to be more specific: that depends where you put that code.

Answer (score 1):

Without modifying anything else, you can change your function signature to:

```
void CenturyOffset(int year, int& offset)
```

This passes a reference which will then modify the variable passed in from `main`, rather than a copy.

However, I would recommend changing the function to use a return:

```
int CenturyOffset(int year){
    int c, y, z, s, d, offset;

    c = year / 100;
    y = year % 100;
    z = y / 4;
    s = c + y + z;
    d = s % 7;
    offset = d;
    if (year % 4 == 0 && year % 400 == 0)
        offset--;
    return offset;
}
```

Now, you can get the value of `offset` in `main`:

```
int offset = CenturyOffset(year);
cout << offset << endl;
OtherFunction(offset);
```

Comment: interesting, i've never seen a variable used that way.

Answer (score 0):

*Mainnote:* Your Leap year logic is incorrect, it should be

```
year % 4 == 0 && year % 100 != 0 || year % 400 == 0
```

---

You have 2 options to return a value:

1) **Use a return value**

In this case You have to change the signature of your method:

```
int CenturyOffset( int year)
```

And in the body of this function You have to write:

```
return offset;
```

Then in the body of your main function you use it as following:

```
int offset = CenturyOffset(year);
```

2) **Return by reference** (some people know it is an **out** value)

In this case You have to change the signature of your method:

```
void CenturyOffset( int year, int& offset)
```

And in the body of the function there is no change.

Then in the body of your main function you use it as following:

```
int offset = 0;                // always should initialize a value before use
CenturyOffset(year, offset);
...
```

Comment: yeah, I realized that about my leap year tonight in class. I was a little off basically. I've been trying to figure that out for a while. Though, I was afraid it wouldn't give me the results I wanted when I looked up a year like 2100.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so I solved this question by using the notes you guys gave me. I decided to use references in-order to get the integer back to the main function. I've acquired another problem however, I will post another question to solve this.

//Declaring Function prototypes
  int dayone(int year, int *offset, int *leapyear);

//Function calls

//This function determines what day the Calendar starts on
  int dayone(int year, int *offset, int *leapyear){
      int c, y, z, s, d;

```
  c = year / 100;
  y = year % 100;
  z = y / 4;
  s = c + y + z;
  d = s % 7;
  *offset = d;
  *leapyear = 0;

    if(year % 4 == 0 || year % 400 == 0 && year % 100 != 0)
        {
            *offset--;
            *leapyear++;
        }
        return *offset, *leapyear;
      }
  //This is in int main(), didn't want to post the rest of the code since I've done a lot since then. 
 dayone(year, &offset, &leapyear);
```

That's what I came up with. I'm sorry if my question was a little confusing. Sometimes I have a hard time explaining what I want to do with a code.